# Hidden files saved by Mac OS X into USB drive

Tags: finder, usb, filesystem, privacy, invisible-files

I inserted some USB device (I don't quite know which partition type it was) into my Mac OS X Yosemite, copied one file from this device into my Mac, and saved one txt file from TextEdit into this device, I then unplugged the device. During this process, which information about my Mac was stored on the USB (for instance, name of the author of the txt file or other metadata, info about my hardware), and where (for instance, in the form of hidden files or logs)?

Answer (score 1):

In the normal course of events, I would not expect any information about your Mac to be transferred to a USB drive.

TextEdit can be configured to contain the Author's name in metadata for Rich Text files (`.rtf`), but not Text files (`.txt`). See TextEdit's Preferences dialog, or File > Show Properties.

The Finder might save a .DS_Store file to the drive, which would contain data about the folders on the disk.e.g. custom icons, position in windows, etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store

No logs or info about your Mac or your username should be copied.